# Sony Vaio not connecting to internet on Wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection, sony-vaio

My Sony Vaio laptop with Windows 2007 installation doesn't connect to internet on Wifi. It used to work all this while (last few years) but this problem started a few weeks back. It works fine when it's on hard wired network. On Wifi, it shows that it's connected to local network but it actually fails to connect to internet.

I have already gone through tons of troubleshooting instruction from Sony Support pages (https://us.en.kb.sony.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/41882/~/how-to-troubleshoot-a-wireless-lan-connection-issue.) and internet but I haven't been successful to fix this.

Laptop Details:

- Sony Vaio Model: VPCEB26GM
- Operating System: Windows 2007
- Network Adapter: Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advances-N 6200 AGN

Comment: Have you tried it with a different WiFi system (eg, your local coffee shop)?

Comment: See [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection) and  
[How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the possible options to troubeshoot Sony Vaio issue, most of them listed here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html

But nothing worked. However when I took my laptop to my work, the WiFI worked fine. So I figured it has to be some problem on my Internet Provider side even though all of my other devices worked fine. I called my ISP and they had to reset my internet settings on their side which fixed the problem of Wifi connectivity. As a reasoning they mentioned that Sony Vaio has a tendency to have Wifi issues when they are moved from one ISP to another in some cases.